# Split text to minimize width while constrained by height on a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have been searching for a week on a lot of forums including stackoverflow and failed finding an answer.

I'm using css flexbox to print dynamic menu items in a responsive website. The text can be long, and if the height enables it, I would like to split the text on several rows, in a way that it will still fit vertically in my div, and that will minimize the width.

I have an example :

HTML

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="text">
        Hello pouc nice to meet you!
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        It would be a great pleasure to help you ;-)
    </div>
    <div class="text">
        Seriously, if ever you had an idea I would be very glad!
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    overflow-x: auto;

    height: 80px;
    width: 400px;
}

.text {
    flex-shrink: 0;

    background: pink;
    margin: 2vh;
}
```

Here is a link of what I'm trying to accomplish :
http://jsfiddle.net/etL630ew/2/

At the top the current result, and at the bottom I injected brs to simulate what I would like to do.

Any answer with CSS only would be great. If I can't do it using CSS, then any js solution would be good too!

Thanks for your time

Pouc

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `flex-shrink: 0` from `.text`

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-x: auto;
  height: 80px;
  width: 400px;
}
.text {
  background: pink;
  margin: 2vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="text">
    Hello pouc nice to meet you!
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    It would be a great pleasure to help you ;-)
  </div>
  <div class="text">
    Seriously, if ever you had an idea I would be very glad!
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! But this does not work if the window resizes to a smaller width (try 150px) as the height is not constrained. Removing the shrink = 0 disables the horizontal scroll bar that I need to keep to make sure that my menu items don't overflow vertically

Answer (score 0):

you could also simply define your width of each text block

```
.finiteWidth{
    width:30%;
    white-space:wrap;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/etL630ew/2/

Comment: I might end up with a solution like this one or some kind of js framework that does it for me. Just hoped there was a neat css trick that I missed...